# Draw rectangle with stroke in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape

How do I draw a simple rectangle with no fill in Inkscape? To my knowledge, the "Stroke style" doesn't give me this option.

[image]

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You might be asking a simple question: How does one change a *selected* shape to have no fill and a black outline? The answers are simple.

- <kbd>Left-click</kbd> [X] in the color palette. <kbd>Right-click</kbd> black in the color palette.
- Access **Object > Fill and Stroke...** from the top menu.

You might be asking a harder question: How does one create shapes with any given style without having to make them first? The answer to that is convoluted, sadly.

You *can* make it so that shapes created take on the "last set color(s)"

1. Access Inkscape's preferences via **Edit > Preferences**
2. Open **Tools > Shapes > Rectangle** (I recommend you change all of them for consistency's sake)
3. Set this preference: **Create new objects with: Last used style**

Now comes the annoying part. You must first create/select a shape and set its color. You can't just select it. After this, the full style is stored in Inkscape's buffer so the next thing you make (in your case, a rectangle) will take on that style.

Comment: does not work at all. V 1.2. Select rectangle. set fill to white, then set stroke to black hoping to have only the edge black, it now fills the rectangle with black.  I tried many times.

Comment: Nasser, it sounds like you are using left-click in the palette for both actions. It's not a sequence of actions. Left-click will always set the fill color. Right-click will always set the stroke color.

Comment: this answer is even more confusing!

Answer (score 1):

An approach — if you just want to 'get it done now' and don't have the time to learn Inkscape or searching for how to solve this — is to draw 4 thin rectangles.  It will give you straight lines if you can correctly eyeball their width.

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced that Stroke paint / Stroke style did not give an outline.

My problem was that I typed 00000000 to get black, but the last two zeros are the alpha channel, making my outline appear in glorious 'invisible black'.

000000FF worked better.